# How to link a branch and work item in Azure DevOps programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to find a way to add a branch as a link in Azure DevOps through an application I'm building ([Basically just this, but within a C# console app](https://www.screencast.com/t/kSa49nWv41)).

I'm becoming familiar with the VisualStudio Services and TeamFoundation .NET libraries and have tried, as an example, to grab a work item with one of these links already created via the DevOps UI and port it to over to another work item like so:

```
var workItemWithBranchLink = await _WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(3985, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations);
var workItemWithoutBranchLink = await _WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(3988, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations);
var document = new JsonPatchDocument();
document.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
{
    Operation = Operation.Add,
    Path = "/relations",
    Value = workItemWithBranchLink.Relations 
});
await _WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(document, (int)workItemWithoutBranchLink.Id);
```

However, this throws an exception

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.PatchOperationFailedException:
>   'Work item patch does not support patching the top level property at
>   path /relations.

Since `workItemWithoutBranchLink.Relations` is null I'm not sure how else I could patch it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For git links the syntax is little different, here it's a working example (to link the `master` branch):

```
VssConnection testConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri("azure-devops-uri"), new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials());
var workItemClient = testConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var gitClient = testConnection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
string projectId = "cf456145-abgd-ffs23-be61-0fca39681234";
string repositoryId = "d6856145-abgd-42a3-be61-0fca3968c555";
var branchUri = string.Format
(
    "vstfs:///Git/Ref/{0}%2f{1}%2f{2}",
    projectId,
    repositoryId,
    "GBmaster"
);

var json = new JsonPatchDocument();
json.Add(
new JsonPatchOperation()
{
     Operation = Operation.Add,
     Path = "/relations/-",
     Value = new
     {
            rel = "ArtifactLink",
            url = branchUri,
            attributes = new
            {
                name = "Branch",
                comment = "Comment"
            }
     }
});

try
{
     int workItemToUpdate = 142144;
     var update = workItemClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(json, workItemToUpdate).Result;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     var error = e.Message;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. You even saved me my next question of how to build the branch uri

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your path to `"/relations/-"`. I am not sure if the patch format in the .net library follows the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link) but seems likely given the top level property error message. i.e. if you add a `/-` you are no longer at the top level.

Also seems to be the format used in this [samples library](https://github.com/redarrowlabs/vsts-restapi-samplecode/blob/61dac20df3ac0bc963181c80223ecd8e25ec908b/VstsClientLibrariesSamples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItems.cs#L190).

Comment: Yup, that was it. That samples library looks very useful for the rest of the project too, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped!